# String concatenation in Wordpress

Tags: php, string, wordpress, concatenation

In my Wordpress site, I am trying to retrieve the most recent 10 posts and store them in a string. After that I will write this content into a text file. Below is the code I am using.

```
<?php $str  = ''; ?>
<?php
require_once('../wp-blog-header.php');
query_posts('&showposts=10&order=DESC&caller_get_posts=1');  
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>     
 <?php $str .= '<a href="' . the_permalink() . '">' .the_title() . '</a>'; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php $fp = fopen("latestposts.txt", "w");
 fwrite($fp, $str);
fclose($fp);?>
```

The problem is, when I execute this page, the permalink and title are returning in this page and empty ''....'' tags are coming in text file. If I am not using the string, the href tags are returning correctly in the same file.

Comment: does just <?php the_permalink(); ?> return anything?

Comment: Any reason why you're opening the file twice without closing it the first time?

Comment: while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>     
   <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
this is working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`the_permalink()` and `the_title()` does not return anything they are to print values.

You have to use their `get_` version. Those are `get_permalink()` and `get_the_title()`

`<?php $str .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' .get_the_title() . '</a>'; ?>`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_the_permalink() in /var/www/pgdeep/data/........... on line 6

Comment: @user: Improved, This is `get_permalink()`. See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks a lot @ShaktiSingh. You saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a wordpress question, but you should be using get_permalink() and get_the_title() instead of the functions you have there. Those functions will echo the link and title, and not return it in string form for use in your concatenation.

Comment: getting this error ->  
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_the_permalink() in /var/www/pgdeep/data/...